# Globalize with Devexpress Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Has anyone used Globalize with Devexpress dateboxes? Cannot find how to make it work, obviously I would like to localize date format for countries like England/Germany/USA etc...

Answer (score 0):

**The sample below applies to AngularJS/Jquery, but you can extrapolate to Angular2**

First of all you have to download the [CLDR](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-core)

Once you downloaded it in **json** format you have to load it into the **Globalize** and set your **locale** see sample code below (see at the bottom of the sample code to check the locale in my case it is *es* for spanish).

```
GlobalizeFunc: function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: localStorage.getItem("urlBase") + '/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    Globalize.load(data);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: localStorage.getItem("urlBase") + '/Scripts/cldr/dates/es/ca-generic.json',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    Globalize.load(data);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: localStorage.getItem("urlBase") + '/Scripts/cldr/dates/es/ca-gregorian.json',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    Globalize.load(data);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: localStorage.getItem("urlBase") + '/Scripts/cldr/dates/es/dateFields.json',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    Globalize.load(data);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: localStorage.getItem("urlBase") + '/Scripts/cldr/dates/es/timeZoneNames.json',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    Globalize.load(data);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: localStorage.getItem("urlBase") + '/Scripts/cldr/numbers/es/numbers.json',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    Globalize.load(data);
                }
            });
            Globalize.locale("es");
        },
```

At this point your controls have been globalized, including calendars and date pickers.